# Keep web changes after refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I just added a dark mode and currency switcher using JS, but the changes don't save after refreshing the page. Does somebody know how to use localStorage on the following codes? Changes can be seen on the following website [Morocco tours](https://www.morocco-excursion.com).

**Dark theme:**

```js
var icon = document.getElementById("icon-phone");

icon.onclick = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");

  if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
    icon.src = "./assets/images/sun.png";
  } else {
    icon.src = "./assets/images/moon.png";
  }
}

var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

icon.onclick = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");

  if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {

    icon.src = "./assets/images/sun.png";
  } else {
    icon.src = "./assets/images/moon.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the localStorage to set and get the values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` to set and `localStorage.getItem('key')` to read a localStorage item.

You could, for example, set `localStorage.setItem('dark-theme', true)` and later retrieve it with `localStorage.getItem('dark-theme')`.

```
var isDarkTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('dark-theme');
if (isDarkTheme === null) {
  isDarkTheme = false;
} else {
  isDarkTheme = isDarkTheme === 'true'
}

var icon = document.getElementById("icon-phone");


if (isDarkTheme) {
  document.body.classList.add('dark-theme')
}

icon.onclick = function () {
  isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme;
  if (isDarkTheme) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem('dark-theme', isDarkTheme);


  if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
    icon.src = "./assets/images/sun.png";
  } else {
    icon.src = "./assets/images/moon.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the following code and didn't work :(

Comment: @HassanMouhou Try the updated code, as localStorage will store the variable as a string and not an actual boolean, you will have to compare it first.

Comment: Now it works thank you. how to o the same for the icons (sun & moon) to not change as well

Comment: @HassanMouhou what do you mean by not change as well? You can move the if statement outside or copy it outside the onclick method to apply when the code is intially executed as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clearly. Now if I click on the moon icon the dark theme is activated, and it shows the sun icon instead. When I refresh the page the dark theme is still activated, but the icon switches back to the moon, I want the sun icon keeps showing while the dark theme is still activated and not to change when I refresh the page.

Comment: @HassanMouhou You can simply copy the last 4 lines of the onclick method and paste it before the onclick method. This way, the image src is set depending on the dark-theme class when the script loads initially.